# How can I refer to an item by id in another QML file?

Tags: qt, qml

So lets say I have the following two qml files:

**main.qml**:

```
    Window {
       /* ... */

       onSomething: mybutton.text = "foo"

       Foo {}
    }
```

**Foo.qml**:

```
Item {
    /* ... */

    Button {
      id: mybutton

      /* ... */
    }
}
```

When `onSomething` is called it will generate a runtime error:

```
ReferenceError: mybutton is not defined
```

Whats the correct way to refer to the `mybutton` button from `mail.qml` ?  Or how else can I organize this?

(Are the `ids` file scoped?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make an alias from your object that want to be accessible like below

**Foo.qml**

```
Item {
property alias buttonText: mybutton.text
/* ... */

Button {
  id: mybutton

  /* ... */
}
```

}

then use it on your main.qml

**main.qml**

```
Window {
   /* ... */

   onSomething: myfoo.buttonText = "foo"

   Foo 
   {
      id: myfoo
   }
}
```

Also you can alias your Button object and use it. As you guess the ids are scoped and you should make them accessible.